# get 403 forbiden when do ajax call on submit event in codeigniter 4

Tags: jquery, csrf, codeigniter-4, websecurity

I used csrf protection in my web

every time i do ajax call i update the csrf token that sended by controller

everything is working fine

my code :

```
var csrfName = '<?= csrf_token() ?>',
    csrfHash = '<?= csrf_hash() ?>';

  $(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/categories/get",
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        [csrfName]: csrfHash,
      },
      success: function(result) {
        // update csrf token
        csrfName = result.csrfName;
        csrfHash = result.csrfHash;

        // my code ..

      },
      error: function(xhr, type, error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: "/services/get",
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        [csrfName]: csrfHash,
      },
      success: function(result) {
        // update csrf token
        csrfName = result.csrfName;
        csrfHash = result.csrfHash;

        // my code ..

      },
      error: function(xhr, type, error) {
        console.log);
      }
    });
```

But when do ajax call on submit event it showed 403 (forbidden),

Code :

```
// Form Order
    $("form#form-order").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let user = $("input[name=user_id]").val();
      let service = $("input[name=service_id").val();
      let data = $("input[name=data]").val();
      let quantity = $("input[name=quantity]").val();

      $.ajax({
        url: "/orders/new",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          user_id: user,
          service_id: service,
          data: data,
          quantity: quantity,
          [csrfName]: csrfHash,
        },
        success: function(result) {
          // update csrf token
          csrfName = result.csrfName;
          csrfHash = result.csrfHash;

          // my code ..

        },
        error: function(xhr,type,error) {
          console.log(error);
        },
      });
    });
```

i always updated csrf token every time i do ajax call

and also, my form doesn't have an action and method attribute to make sure the form isn't submitted and makes the csrf token change

Or this is because variable scope?

please help!

Comment: Does function `new()` inside controller `orders` have `public` visibility?

Comment: Yes it have public visibility

Comment: Please post your controller code, and if you have some routes in place post those too.